# How about sharing our tutorial answers?

Tags: ros, ros-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I just finished the questionnaire and I thought it'd be very interesting to share them to see what other possibilities there is for some answers and in that way learn a bit more about ROS.

Here are mine:

**How do you find the sensor_msgs package?**
rospack find sensor_msgs

**What is the path of the sensor_msgs package?**
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs

**What ROS messages are defined in the sensor_msgs package?**
vim manifest

msg/CameraInfo.msg         msg/JointState.msg        msg/PointCloud.msg
msg/ChannelFloat32.msg     msg/LaserScan.msg         msg/PointField.msg
msg/CompressedImage.msg    msg/NavSatFix.msg         msg/Range.msg
msg/Image.msg              msg/NavSatStatus.msg   msg/RegionOfInterest.msg
msg/Imu.msg                msg/PointCloud2.msg       msg/Joy.msg
msg/JoyFeedback.msg        msg/JoyFeedbackArray.msg

**What nodes and topics are created when running roscore?**
/rosout

**What ROS packages does the roscpp_tutorials package depend on?**
rospack depends roscpp_tutorials

rosbuild
roslang
cpp_common
roscpp_traits
rostime
roscpp_serialization
rospack
roslib
xmlrpcpp
rosconsole
std_msgs
rosgraph_msgs
roscpp
std_srvs

alternative version:
roscd roscpp_tutorials; vim manifest.xml
roscpp, std_srvs, std_msgs

**How do you run the talker and listener nodes in the roscpp_tutorials package?**
rosrun beginner_tutorials talker
rosrun beginner_tutorials listener

**What topic are the talker and listener nodes subscribing and publishing to?**
/chatter (talker publishing to and listener subscribing)

**What is the message type of the topic in the previous question?**
std_msgs/String

**How do you rename a node?**
__name:=

**What is the difference between a topic and a service?**
A service let's you query a node and receive a reply for it, while a topic let's you broadcast messages (nodes can subscribe to the topic).

**What does rxconsole show you?**
rxconsole displays the messages being published to rosout.

**What does roslaunch do?**
Allow you to initialize multiple nodes on your machine.

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11460/how-about-sharing-our-tutorial-answers?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-09**:
I would :-)

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-10-07**:
So far there are 219 responses to the questionnaire. I can anonymize the answers and make them public if that is something that people would like.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-10-07**:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=dGJVOVhyXzd0b0YxRHAxWDdIZmo4cGc6MA but I don't know where its linked from.

**Comment by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) on 2011-10-07**:
can you add a link to the questionnaire?

**Comment by [snakeninny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27179/snakeninny/) on 2016-06-29**:
@mmwise Can you provide us with a piece of "standard" answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are the anonymous answers for ROS and TF tutorials:

https://docs.google.com/a/willowgarage.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApPOAyhQ-WtWdElOelVpbUFia05yaFdrbjVLSzhJWHc#gid=1

Here are some other stats:

**Preferred programming language**

[image: image description]

```
python  57  26%
c++     148 67%
Other   17  8%
```

**How well do you feel you understand ROS concepts after the tutorial?**

[image: image description]

```
Not at all.
1       0      0%
2       0      0%
3       4      2%
4       3      1%
5       9      4%
6       37     17%
7       73     33%
8       43     19%
9       53     24%  
I have a good basic understanding.
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-26**:
Thanks, that's great!